# Problema de ruta, no reconoce un archivo que sé que existe

Tags: php, prestashop

Estoy desarrollando un módulo de Prestashop, estoy programando la configuracion del BackOffice, y necesito tocar un fichero. Tengo la seguridad de que el fichero está escrito bien y de que estoy en el directorio adecuado. ¿Puede haber otro problema?

```
        if (file_exists("fichero.txt")) {
           die ("El fichero existe");
        }else{
            die ("El fichero no existe");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba poniendo la ruta así

```
if (file_exists("./fichero.txt")) 
{
    die ("El fichero existe");
}
else
{
    die ("El fichero no existe");
}
```

El punto (**.**) indica el directorio actual, seguro que es un problema de rutas.

En caso de que no te funcione lo mejor es que indiques la ruta absoluta.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de hacer un test rápido y sí me funcionó así exactamente como lo tienes.

Revisa que efectivamente estén en el mismo lugar, otra cosa que puedes probar es utilizando una url absoluta, pasa el path completo de la localización del archivo y vuelve a correr si sí lo encuentra entonces puede ser que tu archivo lo esté llamando otro que está en otra locación y que toma esa locación como la actual y por eso no lo está leyendo, pero me parece poco probable.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos. Pero ya he encontrado la solución y era otro mi problema.

Resulta que aunque cuando hacía un echo de **FILE** me dijera una ruta, en realidad estaba en la ruta del admin de prestashop. Con $this->_path sí que era capaz de decirme la carpeta actual.